# how to use Zlib to compress more than one file at a time?

Tags: c, zlib

I know `minizip` can do this，but that's too complex. And for some reason i can only include `zlib.h`.

I am try to do this based on `zpipe.c`. I expect to output a `.z` or `.gz` that contains different files (include directory is not necessary).

My way is

`deflateInit()->deflateSetHeader()->fread()->deflate()->fwrite()->deflateEnd()`

, then do it again by open `output.z` again in an additional way.The result is that 2 files be compressed to one file in the `output.z`, that may not be what i want.

Is it possible to  compress more than one file with a few lines of code?

Comment: Note that unlike zip, zlib is not a container format. Thus if you compress multiple files, they will be effectively concatenated together. This is why we typically compress tar files.

Answer (score -1):

You can concatenate the compressed outputs in your zpipe.c based code. 
Do not fclose() the output file. Keep appending to it.

gunzip of the concatenated file is equivalent to `cat file1 file2`. If you
want to recover the multiple files will need to uncat the output file yourself
in your zpipe.c based code. Basically, continue fread() even though inflate()
returned you a Z_STREAM_END.

Here is a proof that concatenating works

```
$ echo "this is file 1" > file1
$ echo "this is file 2" > file2
$ gzip file1
$ gzip file2
$ cat file1.gz file2.gz > files.gz
$ rm file1.gz file2.gz
rm: remove regular file 'file1.gz'? y
rm: remove regular file 'file2.gz'? y
$ gunzip files.gz
$ cat files
this is file 1
this is file 2
```